# Show that the image under sin of the line segment $\{z \in \mathbb{C} : Re\ z = k\}$ is a branch of a hyperbola

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm stuck on this problem:

Show that the image under sin of the line segment $\{z \in \mathbb{C} : Re\ z = k\}$ is a
branch of a hyperbola.

I really have no clue as to how to go about this. Are there any identities or tricks with the sin double angle formula that I'm missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use definition of $\sin z$ and let $z=k+iy$ then find $w=\sin z$.

Answer (score 0):

Under the transformation  $w = \sin z $, we get, $$u + iv = \sin z = \sin (x+iy) $$ $$ = \sin x \cosh y + i\cos x\sinh y $$ Thus, $u = \sin x\cosh y $ and $v =\cos x \sinh y $. Eliminating $y $ from these, we obtain $$\frac{u^2}{\sin^2 x} - \frac {v^2}{\cos^2 x} = 1$$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Form $w=\sin z=\dfrac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$ with supposition $z=k+iy$ then
$$u+iv=\sin z=\dfrac{e^{i(k+iy)}-e^{-i(k+iy)}}{2i}=-\dfrac12\sin k(e^{y}+e^{-y})+i\dfrac12\cos k(e^{y}-e^{-y})$$
then
$$\left(\dfrac{-2u}{\sin k}\right)^2-\left(\dfrac{2v}{\cos k}\right)^2=(e^{y}+e^{-y})^2-(e^{y}-e^{-y})^2=4$$
or
$$\left(\dfrac{u}{\sin k}\right)^2-\left(\dfrac{v}{\cos k}\right)^2=1$$
which shows the equation of a hyperbola!